# PHP DOM parser for HTML and CSS

Tags: php, domparser, css-parsing

Is there any HTML / CSS DOM parser for PHP that I can feed direct live URL and it gives me following two things.

1. HTML of any class/id of the component.
2. Custom CSS that is applied to any class/id.

I know num:1 is possible with so many DOM parser that are available but I also want the CSS properties that are associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [html_dom_parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

which will give you all html finding support

Comment: this does not have any support to parse CSS

Comment: view this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220552/how-should-parse-with-php-simple-html-dom-parser-background-images-and-other-i