# PHP extract specific DIV from target URL

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I'm using Simple HTML DOM to try and extract a div and all of it's contents from a target URL, here is my code:

```
<?php
  require 'simple_html_dom.php';
  $html = file_get_html('http://mozilla.org');
  foreach($html->find('.accordion') as $element) 
      echo $element . '<br>';
?>
```

The problem I have is that the above code only extracts the plain text of the div. There are also images in the div that I need to extract. If I use this following code, then all images are extracted but so is everything else in the page.

```
<?php
  require 'simple_html_dom.php';
  $html = file_get_html('http://mozilla.org');
  echo $html;
?>
```

So my question is, how can I use the first bit of code to extract the contents + images from `.accordion`?

Thanks

Comment: every li in accordion class on http://mozilla.org is having background image through css, therefore please check this to access style properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220552/how-should-parse-with-php-simple-html-dom-parser-background-images-and-other-i

Answer (score 0):

You could always try;

```
$imgs = array();
foreach($html->find('.accordion',0)->find('img') as $img){
    $imgs[] = $img->src;
}

print_r($imgs);
```

This should populate the `$imgs` variable with all of the image links from the `.accordion` div.

:)